# Motion tag for falling block slows down

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Falling blocks with the motion tag don't actually travel infinitely. I tried using a repeating command block to keep setting the motion to [1.0,0.0,0.0], but the falling block's movement ended up being choppy as if it was being teleported.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Command:

```
/summon fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower:0,direction:[1.0,0.0,0.0],power:[1.0,0.0,0.0],Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:falling_block",BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:sand"},Time:1}],Item:{id:"minecraft:sand",Count:1b}}
```

It summons a falling block riding a fireball which travels infinitely (I think) It won't look just like a block but you can adjust the item for the fireball and the block for the falling block. You can adjust the power and direction tag for movement.

Made using:
https://mcstacker.net/

Idea two:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1b,Time:1,Motion:[1.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

No Gravity tag should prevent gravity effects from being used. Which could have been stopping the block?

---

Giant Idea:

```
/summon giant ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1b,Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoAI:1b,Tags:["TPme"],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:sand",Count:1b}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Amplifier:1b,Duration:999999}]}
```

or

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1b,Silent:1b,Invisible:1b,Tags:["TPme"],DisabledSlots:4144959,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:sand",Count:1b}]}
```

Repeat:

```
/execute as @e[tag=TPme] at @s run tp @s ~0.1 ~ ~
```

Comment: I tried doing that already but with a dragon fireball, and it resulted in the same motion but more crazier

Comment: Hmm, how about the no gravity tag? Or how about setting its motion to a really large number?

Comment: I already have the NoGravity enabled, as well as motion being 5.0,0.0,0.0

Comment: Hmm is it a visual thing or the properties of a falling block because we could use an invisible giant wearing a block and have it get constantly teleported. (tp is animated.)

Comment: That might actually work

Comment: I can put the command in the answer. Keep in mind that it will only look like a block :)

Comment: Does it have to be a giant?

Comment: Could be an armor stand or a group of armor stands, a giant's head is the best for the size of a block.